# Why is my selector invalid and throwing an Uncaught DOMException error?

Tags: javascript

I'm coding js for three separate slideshows on my webpage all with the same functionality but I end up getting the error:

"slideshow.js:4 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.[object HTMLElement]__slide' is not a valid selector."

Can anyone help me understand why I'm receiving this error?

The JS code:

```
// Generic slideshow function
function makeSlideshow(key) {
    // Naming the variables
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(`.${key}__slide`);
    const next = document.querySelector(`.${key}__btn--next`);
    const prev = document.querySelector(`.${key}__btn--prev`);
    const auto = true;
    const intervalTime = 5000;
    let slideInterval;

    // more code

}

makeSlideshow(home);
makeSlideshow(about);
makeSlideshow(location);
```

The markup:

```
                <div class="home__slider">
                    <div class="home__slide home__slide--current ss ss-c" style="background: url(img/home/home-1s.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;"></div>
                    <div class="home__slide ss" style="background: url(img/home/home-2s.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;"></div>
                    <div class="home__slide ss" style="background: url(img/home/home-3s.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;"></div>
                    <div class="home__slide ss" style="background: url(img/home/home-4s.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;"></div>
                    <div class="home__btns">
                        <button class="home__btn home__btn--prev bp"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
                        <button class="home__btn home__btn--next bn"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What is `home`, `about` and `location` defined as?

Comment: When you call `makeSlideshow()` you must pass your arguments as strings.

Comment: I'm going to say your problem is when you are calling `makeSlideshow(home);` you are referring to a variable, instead of just passing it as a string: `makeSlideshow('home');`

Comment: @imvain2 Ok great that seems to have worked